# Custom Image Filters in Python - Median Filter with GIMP style color exclusion

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, interpolation

GIMP has a median filter that allows you to exclude certain colors from consideration (enhance-> despeckle -> white level). It allows me to mask out part of an image (in say pure white) and have it filled in by the median local color.

How do I replicate that behavior in Python?

Both opencv and Python Image Library have median filters, but neither allow a white level or mask.

Both allow custom filters, but I haven't figured out how to write a nonlinear filter, particularly with exclusion of colors.

Opencv inpaint works, but is very very slow for the application i'm using.

scipy.interpolate.griddata softens edges for cubic interpolate, and produces bad results with nearest neighbor (I want the local median/mode and it ends up duplicating speckles/stray pixels).

Does anyone know how to write a fast nonlinear filter including a mask?

or

Is there something else off the shelf I should try that's fast?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Found a similar question asked in terms of Scipy-ndimage filters and numpy masked arrays, but also with no answer.

http://scipy-user.10969.n7.nabble.com/ndimage-masked-array-handling-tt17547.html#none

Comment: There's a NaN aware linear filter
http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/nddata/convolution.html
Which is discussed here
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/1682
But still no median or mode.